# chrome.webRequest doesn't catch all requests

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm writing chrome extension and I need to catch all requests from the beginning of downloading page.
I'm using `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest` in `background.js`, and send them to `content.js` for logging. 
But I don't see all requests. It looks like `background.js` start working with delay (and I missing important requests). How can I avoid it?

Here is my `background.js`:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(logURL, { urls: ["<all_urls>"] });
function logURL(requestDetails) {
  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(
      tabs[0].id,
      { message: requestDetails.url },
      function(response) {}
    );
  });
}
```

and content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.message == "reload") {
    location.reload();
    console.log("reload");
  } else {
    console.log(request.message);
  }
});
```

How can I catch all request or run my `background.js` previously? Maybe I have made mistakes and can't find them?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If somebody will have the same mistake:
chrome.webRequest catch all requests, but content.js file inject later (after few requests).
So you should collect requests in background.js and send them after content.js injection (for example you can send a message to background.js).

Comment: I have the same problem, the page starts making requests before I inject my script. Can you provide an example with your solution? Thanks!